# My SMTP service is not sending messages to external addresses

Tags: php, smtp, external

I have a local server which host PHP applications. My applications send emails to different addresses. However, I am noticing a problem that I am unable to figure out. It send emails to internal addresses but it won't send messages to external addresses.

I also have an exchange server on the same network.  so for example I have these 2 "internal domain"

domain1.com
domain2.com

if I execute this php function from my application it gets delivered with no problem

```
mail("name@domain1.com","Test Subject","Test message");
```

However, if I try sening a message to gmail, yahoo or any external domain it does not send it

```
mail("name@gmail.com","Test Subject","Test message");
```

My server is running on Windows 2008 Server R2 with PHP5.3.19 installed on it via IIS6

How Can I correct this issue?

Comment: Check your mail log...

Comment: What does this actually mean: "does not send it"? If you find out that, you have your cause and thus your solution. But we cannot guess what is going on inside your systems. You will have to look at the log files yourself...

Comment: Does not send mean they don't go any were. In face yesterday I got an email notification from postmaster to notify me that the messages has been delayed. Can you please point me to the right direction? Where are the log files located at?

Answer (score 0):

`mail()` on Windows needs extra config in php.ini because Windows does not have Sendmail or anything similar.

The first is the `SMTP` setting which should point to your ISP's *outbound* server which is not necessarily the same server that you retrieve your mail from. When I worked in support there were a lot of issues like you describe because an inbound server will still accept mail, but only for the domains that are local to it.

The second is the `sendmail_from` setting, which is what the gimpy little mailer PHP wrote for the Windows distribution uses in every SMTP transaction regardless of what's in the headers. On *nix Sendmail will read the headers and get the `From:` address itself, on Windows PHP will always use what's in php.ini. If this is a "garbage" address like `example@example.com` or something with a non-existant domain many mail servers will reject it outright. What I recommend is to change it to something decent in PHP.ini *as well as* adding the following line to your mailing scripts:

```
ini_set('sendmail_from', $from_address);
```

Alternatively, just use [PHPmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer) since it simply *works much better* than PHP's horrid little `mail()` function.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation here. regarding the second solution I don't think this is it because I have listed there a valid email address so this eliminate that as an option. However, the first one I think is a good answer but I need your help to solve it. I am not good when it comes to servers and transfer protocols and all good stuff. This is my first experience with this. So how can I tell what is my ISP's outbound server? where in php.ini do I list that? I do have an exchange server on my network which we user to send email.

Comment: @Mike If you don't know for sure which server is used for outbound, ask. And the setting in php.ini is literally named `SMTP`, eg: `SMTP = smtp.somedomain.com`